# Convert a String into an array with Keycodes

Tags: objective-c, keycode

today i started with a simple Project that should convert a string into an array with keycodes to simulate keystrokes. 
My Problem is that i cant use a char as an id for a dictionary to convert that char into the keycode.

```
//Declare a Dictionary
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

//Add the Basic data for keycodes (i know that there are some missing)
[dictionary setObject:@"0x00" forKey:@"a"]; //a
[dictionary setObject:@"0x0B" forKey:@"b"]; // b
[dictionary setObject:@"0x08" forKey:@"c"]; //c
[dictionary setObject:@"0x02" forKey:@"d"]; // d
[dictionary setObject:@"0x0E" forKey:@"e"]; //e
[dictionary setObject:@"0x03" forKey:@"f"]; //f
[dictionary setObject:@"0x05" forKey:@"g"]; //g
[dictionary setObject:@"0x04" forKey:@"h"]; //h
[dictionary setObject:@"0x22" forKey:@"i"]; //i
[dictionary setObject:@"0x26" forKey:@"j"]; //j
[dictionary setObject:@"0x28" forKey:@"k"]; //k
[dictionary setObject:@"0x25" forKey:@"l"];//l
[dictionary setObject:@"0x2D" forKey:@"m"];//m
[dictionary setObject:@"0x2E" forKey:@"n"];//n
[dictionary setObject:@"0x1F" forKey:@"o"];//o
[dictionary setObject:@"0x23" forKey:@"p"];//p
[dictionary setObject:@"0x0C" forKey:@"q"];//q
[dictionary setObject:@"0x0F" forKey:@"r"];//r
[dictionary setObject:@"0x01" forKey:@"s"];//s
[dictionary setObject:@"0x11" forKey:@"t"];//t
[dictionary setObject:@"0x20" forKey:@"u"];//u
[dictionary setObject:@"0x09" forKey:@"v"];//v
[dictionary setObject:@"0x0D" forKey:@"w"];//w
[dictionary setObject:@"0x07" forKey:@"x"];//x
[dictionary setObject:@"0x10" forKey:@"y"];//y
[dictionary setObject:@"0x06" forKey:@"z"];//z

NSString *workwith = [_mess stringValue]; //Get String from Interface
long stringl = [workwith length]; //Get lenght of the String
int a = 0;
char text[stringl-1]; //make a array with the lenght of the string
while (a < stringl) { //fill this array with chars from the string
    text[a] = [workwith characterAtIndex:a];
    NSLog(@"%c",text[a]);
    a++;

}
char fmat[stringl-1]; //make a second char to fill it with keycodes
int dnehmen = 0;
while (dnehmen <= stringl-1) {
    fmat[dnehmen] = [dictionary objectForKey:@"%c",text[dnehmen]]; //stuck at this point
```

}

At the last line i try to use a char from the first array as an id for the dictionary to get the keycode for the second array. 
I get an error that i cant use a char as an id and so i need a was to get the keycode from a char.
(I read some Posts on this site but i didn`t really understood what they´ve done)
Thanks for your answers
Tim

Answer (score 0):

The error you report is down to the line:

```
fmat[dnehmen] = [dictionary objectForKey:@"%c",text[dnehmen]];
```

as `@"%c",text[dnehmen]` does not return an object but a `char` value due to the use of the rather obscure C comma operator - a comma is usually a separator but is also an operator (like `+` etc.) which just returns its second argument. So you get an error referring to characters...

Given that you've used `NSString` values as keys what you need is a string containing your character and you probably meant to type:

```
fmat[dnehmen] = [dictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",text[dnehmen]]];
```

While that will fix your first problem you now have another, your dictionary returns an `NSString` containing four characters and your code suggests you'd like the byte (`char`) represented by those four characters when interpreted by a compiler as a hexadecimal literal...

At this point you might be tempted to try to convert the string into a byte value by parsing it as a hexadecimal number, but you shouldn't. Instead look at putting the value you need into the `NSDictionary` in the first place. Both the objects any keys used in an `NSDictionary` can be *any* [1] type of object. You might want to consider using `NSNumber` objects for both.

Hopefully that will set you off on the right track in fixing your design.

[1] Well *almost* any to be precise, any which have equality and hash methods - which in practice is everything that descends from `NSObject` so don't worry about this pedantic detail now!